# How to store count text inside a .popover after closing and reopening it again?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I stored the input value with the `.inputincreasebusiness1` class after closing and reopening the `.popover`:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="goactiontextinc1">
    Click
  </button>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var inputVal = {}; // Objeto para armazenar os valores dos inputs
      var popoverOpen = false; // Variável para controlar o estado do popover

      // Função para abrir o popover e definir o valor dos inputs
      function openPopover() {
        $('#goactiontextinc1').popover('show');
        var popover = $('.popover');
        $('#inputCategoria').each(function() {
          var inputId = $(this).attr('id');
          $(this).val(inputVal[inputId]);
        });
        popoverOpen = true;
      }

      // Função para fechar o popover
      function closePopover() {
        $('#goactiontextinc1').popover('hide');
        popoverOpen = false;
      }

      // Ao clicar no botão para abrir ou fechar o popover
      $('#goactiontextinc1').on('click', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (popoverOpen) {
          closePopover();
        } else {
          openPopover();
        }
      });

      // Ao clicar em qualquer parte do documento
      $(document).on('click', function(event) {
        var target = $(event.target);
        if (!target.closest('#goactiontextinc1').length && !target.closest('.popover').length && popoverOpen) {
          closePopover();
        }
      });

      // Ao digitar nos inputs dentro do popover
      $(document).on('input', '.popover input', function() {
        var inputId = $(this).attr('id');
        inputVal[inputId] = $(this).val();
        checkInputLength();
      });

      // Inicialização do popover
      $('#goactiontextinc1').popover({
        html: true,
        sanitize: false,
        placement: 'bottom',
        container: 'body',
        title: 'POP TITLE',
        content: 'Type:<br><input class="inputincreasebusiness1" type="text" id="inputCategoria"><br><p class="messagecounttagsp1" id="idcountmessageinc1"></p>',
        trigger: 'manual'
      });

      // Ao abrir o popover, preenche os inputs com os valores armazenados
      $('#goactiontextinc1').on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
        $('.inputincreasebusiness1').each(function() {
          var inputId = $(this).attr('id');
          $(this).val(inputVal[inputId]);
        });
        checkInputLength();
      });

      // Ao fechar o popover, armazena os valores dos inputs
      $('#goactiontextinc1').on('hidden.bs.popover', function() {
        $('.inputincreasebusiness1').each(function() {
          var inputId = $(this).attr('id');
          inputVal[inputId] = $(this).val();
        });
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>
```

I can store the input value even after closing and reopening the `.popover`.

But when I try to store the character count I can't. See the `JS` code I put separately from the first code:

```
$(function() {
  // Ao abrir o popover, preenche os inputs com os valores armazenados
  $('#goactiontextinc1').on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    $('.messagecounttagsp1').each(function() {
      var inputId = $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).text(inputVal[inputId]);
    });
  });

  // Ao fechar o popover, armazena os valores dos inputs
  $('#goactiontextinc1').on('hidden.bs.popover', function() {
    $('.messagecounttagsp1').each(function() {
      var inputId = $(this).attr('id');
      inputVal[inputId] = $(this).text();
    });
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#inputCategoria', function() {
    $('#inputCategoria').on('input', function() {
      var inputLength = $(this).val().length;
      var remainingChars = 10 - inputLength;

      if (remainingChars > 0) {
        $('#idcountmessageinc1').text(remainingChars + ' caracteres restantes');
        $(this).next('.fa').remove();
      } else {
        $('#idcountmessageinc1').text('');
        $(this).next('.fa').remove();
        $(this).after('<i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="color:green; margin-left: 5px;"></i>');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

But when I close and reopen the `.popover`, only the input value is stored, but the `<p class="messagecounttagsp1">` tag with the remaining characters disappears after closing and reopening the `.popover`.

- How to store the count value inside the `.popover` even closing and reopening infinite times?

Comment: Can you show your HTML? it's hard to tell what is wrong if you don't show it.

Comment: The HTML is inside the `content`: `.popover({content='HTML'})`